# Detecting "\" (backslash) using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a C# Regex like

```
[\"\'\\/]+
```

that I want to use to evaluate and return error if certain special characters are found in a string.

My test string is:

```
\test
```

I have a call to this method to validate the string:

```
public static bool validateComments(string input, out string errorString)
{
    errorString = null;
    bool result;

    result = !Regex.IsMatch(input, "[\"\'\\/]+");  // result is true if no match
                                                   // return an error if match

    if (result == false)
        errorString = "Comments cannot contain quotes (double or single) or slashes.";

    return result;
}
```

However, I am unable to match the backslash.  I have tried several tools such as regexpal and a VS2012 extension that both seem to match this regex just fine, but the C# code itself won't.  I do realize that C# is escaping the string as it is coming in from a Javascript Ajax call, so is there another way to match this string?

It does match /test or 'test or "test, just not \test

Comment: This is more efficient and more readable than regex: `input.Contains('\\')`

Comment: @Tim I'm actually looking for multiple characters.

Comment: It was just an example. Here's another for the quotes: `input.Contains('"') || input.Contains('\'');`. You could also put the characters in an array and use linq to evaluate the input: `bool anyQuotes=quotesChars.Any(c=>input.Contains(c))`.

Comment: So appending all 4 checks together is better than a Regex?

Comment: In terms of readability (for most people) and efficiency? Yes. String methods are almost always faster than regex, if you can use them at all.

Comment: I figured on a single case basis that would be true, but it gets a little more fuzzy with multiple check (e.g. check the string for x, then y, then z, and so on...).  Although technically I guess that is what the Regex is doing also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `\` is used even by Regex(es). Try `"[\"\'\\\\/]+"` (so double escape the `\`)

Note that you could have `@"[""'\\/]+`" and perhaps it would be more readable :-) (by using the `@` the only character you have to escape is the `"`, by the use of a second `""`)

You don't really need the `+`, because in the end `[...]` means "one of", and it's enough for you.

Don't eat what you can't chew... Instead of regexes use

```
// result is true if no match
result = input.IndexOfAny(new[] { '"', '\'', '\\', '/' }) == -1;
```

I don't think anyone ever lost the work because he preferred `IndexOf` instead of a regex :-)

Comment: That looks really strange, but yes, it works.  Escape characters... go figure.

Comment: @Philethius There are tons of expressions in Regexes like `\w` (match any word character), so it's normaly that the `\ ` must be escaped. Then you have to fight against the escaping of the string, so `\\\\ `  (or better, always use `@"..."` when writing regexes)

Comment: Yes that makes sense.  I'll make a mental note about being more explicit with Regexes in my code.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this by making the string verbatim like this `@`:

```
result = !Regex.IsMatch(input, @"[\""\'\\/]+");
```

Comment: Definitely the best idea with Regex. Double escaping backslashes is really confusing, and verbatim strings really help remove the confusion.

Comment: Corrected the quotes (these are the only thing that need escaping with verbatim strings)

Comment: @Philethius Actually he doesn't need to escape those two anyway.

Comment: @spender Thank you, you are correct. I just remembered you need the double the quotes in a verbatim string, good catch :)

Comment: It doesn't sound like you can completely stop escaping or doubling... pick your poison.

Answer (score 2):

Since backslashes are used as escapes inside regex themselves, I find it best to use verbatim strings when working with the regex library:

```
string input = @"\test";
bool result = !Regex.IsMatch(input, @"[""'\\]+");
//                                     ^^
// You need to double the double-quotes when working with verbatim strings;
// All other characters, including backslashes, remain unchanged.
if (!result) {
    Console.WriteLine("Comments cannot contain quotes (double or single) or slashes.");
}
```

The only issue with that is that you must double your double-quotes (which is ironically what you need to do in your case).

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/Sz23Fn).

Answer (score 0):

For the trivial case, I am able to use regexhero.net for your test expression using the simple:

```
\\
```

to validate

```
\test
```

The code generated by RegExHero:

```
string strRegex = @"\\";

RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
string strTargetString = @"\test";
foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
    // Add your code here
  }
}
```